# Adding a variable to xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath

I am currently trying to figure out how to try and use a variable in an xpath.

Example: 
/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]
I would like to make it where it says div[3] into something where it replaces the 3 with a variable. I've been trying to figure it out but don't have any luck. Was wondering if someone knew how. ~ Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using f-strings or `.format()` ? Something like this.

```
for i in range(10):
    some_xpath = f"/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[{i}]/button[2]"
    print(some_xpath)
```

Comment: Ah yes thank you. I went for this approach instead:            

`i = 5
while True: 

    some_xpath = f"/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[{i}]/button[2]"
    print(some_xpath)
    i +=1
    time.sleep(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that is the lxml `xpath` function (https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method) then it has support for XPath variables in a simple way, you pass them as named arguments to the function e.g.

```
tree.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[$pos]/button[2]", pos = 3)
```